# android Retrofit2 with OkHTTP3 sequence call with unexpected same result

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using android Retrofit2 with OkHTTP3 and i need to call same api twice. and take action based on each response but i got old response always.

how to clear old response every time api called?

Here is my code

```
 @GET("/state/{id}")
Observable<Result<ResponseStateModel>> getStateById(@Path("id") String id);

public class CachingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        request = new Request.Builder()
                .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxAge(0, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .minFresh(0, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .maxStale(0, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .build())
                .url(request.url())
                .build();


        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

  okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(new CachingInterceptor())
            .cookieJar(new AppCookieJar())
            .authenticator(authenticator)
            .build();


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_details);
    getState();
   }
```

Here the called api method

```
public void getState(){
 BackgroundThreadObservable.toBackground(getStateById(Id))
        .subscribe(new Action1<Result<ResponseStateModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.Result<ResponseStateModel> ResponseStateModel) {
        Log.e("response => ", new Gson().toJson(ResponseStateModel));
         btnChangeState.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    });
 }

 btnChangeState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           changeState();
        }
    });
```

change state method and call get state again

```
public void changeState(){
BackgroundThreadObservable.toBackground(changeStateById(Id))
    .subscribe(new Action1<Result<ResponseChangeStateModel>>() {
@Override
public void call(retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.Result<ResponseChangeStateModel> responseChangeStatetModel) {

    Log.e("response => ", new Gson().toJson(responseChangeStatetModel));

    if (responseChangeStatetModel.response().body().getState().getIs_change() == false) {
          Log.e("State", "false");

   }else if (responseChangeStatetModel.response().body().getState().getIs_change() == true) {

              getState(Id);
          }
    }
});
```

Regrads,

Comment: post the relevant code parts (creating & configuration of httpClient, code used for calling API)

Comment: it doesn't make sense to get old response , that is mean you using caching mechanism , which provide you with the old response for your same request .

Comment: @Yazan question edited, please check it.

Comment: @AhmedEltaher as i know retrofit not support cache by default and i'm not using any cache mechanism as edited in question now.

Comment: @Safa Im pretty sure that you pass same `Id` to both requests.

Comment: i don't see you are using/setting cache, so how did you know it's the same response? from logs? or ?? also why it should be different ? maybe your request parameters not correct or the same in each call? or this is the supposed to be correct response (from server side) post IN and OUT logs for your call, it could show something helpful.

Comment: @Divers yes i'm using same id but after call some changes in backend, check updated code please.

Comment: @Yazan response should change after call changeState() method but i found in log that, the getState() method always return old response which get when calling t from onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this interceptor:

```
public class CachingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        request = new Request.Builder()
                .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxAge(0, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .minFresh(0, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .maxStale(0, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .build())
                .url(request.url())
                .build();


        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me more what this interceptor do and where    should i add it.

Comment: you already have an interceptor (logging). add it to okhttpbuilder class

Comment: like this okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CachingInterceptor())
                .cookieJar(new AppCookieJar())
                .authenticator(authenticator)
                .build();

Comment: Yes, Also you can add several interceptors

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. But i made two objects from `OkHttpClient` as there was a crash with requests that invoked one time.